# mvn jetty:run Deploys but geting Service Unavailable 503

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I currently added the jetty maven plugin to my project, but after running, It seems to run but getting 503. My Web Application seem running normally as all spring web ap

```
Feb 11, 2016 1:50:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/api/city/v1/update],
Feb 11, 2016 1:22:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 29097 ms
2016-02-11 13:22:55.016:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@18f56b9{/myapp,file:///home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:///home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/src/main/webapp/}
2016-02-11 13:50:38.313:INFO:/smartinsure:main: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.interswitchng.techquest.smartinsure.rest.config.WebXml@1ebb1b6]
2016-02-11 13:50:38.781:WARN:/smartinsure:main: unavailable
```

My Configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds> 
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8081</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
        </connectors>z
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is log when jetty begins deploying

```
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ myapp ---
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [INFO] Copying 2 resources
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myapp ---
 [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run (default-cli) @ myapp <<<
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M2:run (default-cli) @ myapp ---
 2016-02-11 13:49:47.315:INFO::main: Logging initialized @10630ms
 [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: myapp
 [INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
 [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
 [INFO] Classes = /home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/target/classes
 [INFO] Context path = 
 [INFO] Tmp directory = /home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/target/tmp
 [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
 [INFO] Web overrides =  none
 [INFO] web.xml file = file:///home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
 [INFO] Webapp directory = /home/osboxes/develop/projects/java/myapp/src/main/webapp
 2016-02-11 13:49:47.562:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.0.M2
```

Any Help?

Comment: can you share its configuration? is that the only error you get?

Comment: This error is often followed by other stacktraces/errors (i.e. a spring bean not initialized due to misconfiguration). You don't have any other error in your console?

Comment: I dont have that kind of error

Comment: Also, Jetty `9.3.0.M2` is an unstable milestone build.  Use something stable / recent.  Jetty `9.3.7.v20160115` would be the most recent stable release in the Jetty 9.3.x line.